# Populate a column with values from 2 locations

Tags: sql-server

In the SQL below, the Bank column returns an emty string ('') if the select cannot find a value in the lookup table. Rather than an empty string, I want to show the value in the field b.BankName

```
SELECT 
' ' AS DUMMY, 
c.CustomerNumber AS DirectDebitRef,
(SELECT replace(bankname, 'Other (please specify)', '')
 FROM Banks
 WHERE bankid = b.bankid) AS Bank, 
b.SortCode AS SortCode
FROM 
dbo.Customers AS c 
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerBanks AS b ON c.CustomerBankId = b.CustomerBankId
INNER JOIN dbo.View_CustomerBillingsToday AS v ON c.CustomerId = v.CustomerId 
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAddressBillings AS s ON c.CustomerAddressBillingId = s.CustomerAddressBillingId
```

The moment I add b.BankName i get NULL output in all the rows that have a valid lookup. If I replace b.BankName with say 'x' I get a value in all rows. So I know the replace works but when i try to reference the fieldname that works but it nulls all the other rows

```
replace( (SELECT        bankname
                               FROM            Banks
                               WHERE        bankid = b.bankid), 'Other (please specify)', b.BankName) AS Bank
```

Comment: What is the `b.Other` field?

Comment: Its the field that stores a string when the drop list is not holding the item

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you want 2 fields in the output - `bankname` when it's in the list, and `other` when it isn't?

Comment: I updated the Question with more info, the other field is called b.BankName. Sorry I called it other before - confusing. Yeah Shree, thats what i'm after, the value from the lookup table, but if its Other (please specify) then show value in b.BankName.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand where the other value is stored. Can you try to create SQL Fiddle, or at least post your table design here?

Comment: Other value (BankName) is stored in CustomerBanks  table hence the prefix of 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case statement worked, using that instead of replace did the trick :-)

```
 case WHEN (SELECT bankname
                               FROM            Banks
                               WHERE        bankid = b.bankid) = 'Other (Please Specify)' THEN b.BankName
                               ELSE (SELECT bankname
                               FROM            Banks
                               WHERE        bankid = b.bankid)
                               END AS Bank
```